# Getting contents within ( ) and using that later

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a code so far with regex to replace the content that shouldn't be there   EX:

```
var a = $('.uTubeE').attr('href').replace(/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/g,'');
        $('.uTubeE').attr('href',a).text(a).attr('title',$1);
```

Text to remove from looks like this:

```
<a href="www.url.com(content)">www.url.com(content)</a>
```

As you can see I am trying to use the content I remove as the title attribute now, I know the var a is wrong since I am replacing the content. I'm not sure how to grab it though because once I do that I can then simply do this-

```
  var correct= $('.uTubeE').attr('href').replace($1);
  $('.uTubeE').attr({
     href: correct,
     title: $1
     }).text(correct);
```

just not sure how to do it all correctly.

Any suggestions and help with using the regex?

New Issue states there is 0 of undefined>

```
var a = $(forum[yourVersion]+' a[href*="watch?v"]');
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
     var xyx = a[i].href.match(/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/);
     var b = a[i].href.replace(new RegExp("watch\\?v=", "i"), 'v/');
     a[i].href= b;
     var cc = b.replace(/(www\.)?youtube.com/, 'img.youtube.com');
     var dd = cc.replace('v','vi').replace(xyx[0],'');
     a[i].outerHTML= '<a class="uTubeE" rel="vid_gallery" title="'+xyx[1]+'" href="' + b + '"><span class="uTubeE_overlay"></span><img src="'+ dd +'/0.jpg"/></a>';
     }
```

Comment: You should `match` first, to get whatever's inside the parentheses, *then* replace.

Comment: ok so then I do this

/\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/.match($('.uTubeE'))

then? I forgot about match and never use it so i'm sorta new here :D

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). `match` is a String method, whhich means you would invoke it as a method of whatever string you want to match against. `$('.uTubeE')` is a jQuery collection, and I suppose you're looking to match against the `href` attribute, so you would use: `$('.uTubeE').attr('href').match(/yourregex/)`

Comment: Thanks Asad I'll be reading it

Comment: @Asad can you look at my new issue posted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there’s only one parenthesized thing to remove, use `exec`:

```
var href = $('.uTubeE').attr('href');
var match = /\(((\s*?.*?)*?)\)/.exec(href);
```

Now your content is in `match[1]`, and you can fix the `href` by doing

```
href =
    href.substring(0, match.index) +
    href.substring(match.index + match[0].length);
$('.uTubeE').attr('href', href);
```

Comment: Ok I believe I may have the wrong regex, I don't want the parenthesis at all. Just (content) to be content after. could you help with that?

Comment: @EasyBB: I don’t understand… your link looks like `<a href="www.url.com(content)">`. What should the URL look like afterward the replacement?

Comment: `www.url.com` just that, and title will be `title="content"`

Comment: @EasyBB: Okay. So use `match[1]`, not `match[0]` as the title.

Comment: wow how did that work so well? Sorry that just confused me just a wee bit haha! It worked amazingly simple

Comment: @EasyBB: Matching is what `exec`’s for :) As for removing it, that just takes the part before the match (character 0 to the start of the match) and concatenates the part after the match (the start of the match plus the match’s length to the end of the string).

Comment: Hey having a new issue, please look at the new code added above

Comment: @EasyBB If you're having a different issue, that should go in a new question (after you've done your due diligence in trying to debug it yourself).

Comment: Oh I've been debugging haha. Console logging everything. I will make a new question, that is no problem. I'll take another whack at it, then I'll post new question. Thanks Asad